# Extract substring between two delimiters and output into calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I'm currently having an issue with extracting a substring between two delimiters and outputting into a computed column.

I have a some strings in a column called short_description that look like this:

```
"ABCD-0291 job SRT_FBEW_DNBADQAAGR in process published with status code 32"
"ABCD-0431 job DBDE_FKFW_MDNSQA in process published with status code 14"
"ABCD-0075 job SHFGF_RTBL_MJBVXW in process published with status code 19"
```

I basically need a way to extract just the part after the second space but before the third space. So the values returned from the query should be:

```
SRT_FBEW_DNBADQAAGR
DBDE_FKFW_MDNSQA
SHFGF_RTBL_MJBVXW
```

I know substring with charindex might be a way to do it but I'm unsure how to apply it in my specific example, any help is appreciated.

I have tried this code:

```
Alter table Test_Data
Add substring_1 AS case when short description LIKE 'ABCD%' then 
LEFT(substring(short_description,
charindex(' ', short_description) +1, len(short_description)), charindex(' ', substring(short_description, charindex(' ', short_description) +2, len(short_description)))) end
```

however the output returns "job" which is not what I want.

Comment: You'll work it out soon enough if you mess around with charindex and substring, looks to me like find the second space and substring to the third space?

Comment: @DaleK I have updated the question with the code i have tried with

Comment: Your code is not complete e.g. where does `ADD` come into it? You need to create a [mre] like Larnu has done, including the sample data in your attempt.

Comment: @DaleK sorry I am still learning the ins and outs of sql I have added the part "Alter table" to the query i tried

Comment: So you actually want this as a computed column, @Mackem2020 ..? That completely moves the goal posts...

Comment: @Larnu yes exactly a computed column

Comment: @Mackem2020 do please try and ensure your future questions are whole and complete to avoid people spending time on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is a few nested calls to `CHARINDEX`. I do this in some `VALUES` constructs, so as not to need to repeat the calls:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(V.YourColumn,CI2.I+1, CI3.I - CI2.I - 1) AS YourSubString
FROM (VALUES('ABCD-0291 job SRT_FBEW_DNBADQAAGR in process published with status code 32'),
            ('ABCD-0431 job DBDE_FKFW_MDNSQA in process published with status code 14'),
            ('ABCD-0075 job SHFGF_RTBL_MJBVXW in process published with status code 19'))V(YourColumn)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourColumn)))CI1(I)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourColumn,CI1.I + 1)))CI2(I)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourColumn,CI2.I + 1)))CI3(I)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb2ae0a6d6df9dc9781a4605774b648c)

This will, however, fail if there are not 3 white spaces in your value.

---

Seems like the OP *actually* wants this as a computed column. Rather than using a different solution, I have taken the above, and turned it into a scalar expression:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD YourSubString AS SUBSTRING(YourColumn,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn) + 1) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn) + 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn) + 1) - 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6d5160aef2cddc5538a51849017c335)

Again, if there aren't 3 whitespaces this will generate an error; I am assuming that all the values are valid for the above expression in your source data. If this is not the case, I would suggest asking a new question now, as the goal posts have already been moved once.

Comment: thats not exactly what I envisoned, I attached some code that I have tried in the question but returns the wrong output maybe you can see where im going wrong?

Comment: The code in your question looks nothing like my solution above, @Mackem2020 .There's a`CASE` expression in there, and `LEFT`, it's not what I've written here. The above, however, does work for the sample data we have; is your sample data not reflective of your real data? If so, that's the problem...

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the answer, demonstrating this works for the data you've supplied, @Mackem2020 .

Comment: okay i will take a look, the data i have is like 100,000 rows long i only supplied 3 rows to simplify the question. I have other strings in the same column that are not of the same format but i dont really care to much about them hence why i use the LIKE operator to match on just ABCD

Comment: I have added a scalar expression to use as a computed column, @Mackem2020 , but it comes with the same caveat.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you, your scalar expression worked just as I wanted it to. Im also sorry for the confussion I will try to be more clear and concise in my future questions. Have a great day!

Comment: If the answer does provide the solution you need, @Mackem2020 , please do mark it as the solution; this tells future readers it is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a `CASE` expression to catch values that don't have three spaces, and return `NULL` rather than failing?

Comment: It was a consideration when i wrote the first solution, @MatBailie ; you could actually just wrap the `CHARINDEX` functions in a `NULLIF`. Though for the second solution it's going to make it even uglier. 

Comment: That's the price people pay for pushing their string processing out of an ETL layer and in to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the value is not repeated in the string, you can use `string_split()` with some comparisons to get the third value:

```
select *
from t cross apply
     (select s.value
      from string_split(t.col, ' ') s
      where t.col like '% % ' + s.value + ' %' and
            t.col not like '% % % ' + s.value + ' %'
     ) s;
```

The value also has a very specific form, so you can look for that:

```
select *
from t cross apply
     (select s.value
      from string_split(t.col, ' ') s
      where s.value like '%[_]%[_]%'
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=76e6230970d799df2e067cbc7599273d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think this way is also very useful how would one go about incorporating a LIKE 'ABCD%' as the output from you query should only return values when there is a match on ABCD at the start of the string. Also there was some confusion in the question listed but instead of outputting to a temporary table can these outputs be placed in a calculated column?

Comment: @Mackem2020 . . . `string_split()` won't work for a calculated column, although it can be used in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential idea : Use the `STUFF` function to remove the first space, replace the second space with a special character and replace the third space with another special character; then use the `SUBSTRING` function.

Here's a test example :

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABCD-0291 job SRT_FBEW_DNBADQAAGR in process published with status code 32' 

SET @Value = STUFF(@Value, CHARINDEX(' ', @Value), 1, '')
SET @Value = STUFF(@Value, CHARINDEX(' ', @Value), 1, '~')
SET @Value = STUFF(@Value, CHARINDEX(' ', @Value), 1, '`')

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Value, CHARINDEX('~', @Value) + 1, CHARINDEX('`', @Value) - CHARINDEX('~', @Value) - 1)
```

I have no idea what the performance is like on the above idea, but maybe it can help in some way.

Also remember it makes use of 2 special characters; which means it won't work correctly in the cases where those characters show up normally, and it also probably won't work in cases where there aren't 3 spaces in it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use STRING_SPLIT. The thing is that it returns a new table, so I'm not sure if it suits your needs. Nevertheless, the following code works:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (
    colID int IDENTITY,
    yourString varchar(max)
)

INSERT  INTO @yourTable
VALUES  
    ('ABCD-0291 job SRT_FBEW_DNBADQAAGR in process published with status code 32'),
    ('ABCD-0431 job DBDE_FKFW_MDNSQA in process published with status code 14'),
    ('ABCD-0075 job SHFGF_RTBL_MJBVXW in process published with status code 19')

DECLARE @idColumn int
DECLARE @strToSubstr varchar(max)

SELECT @idColumn = MIN(colID) 
FROM @yourTable

WHILE @idColumn IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT @strToSubstr = yourString 
    FROM @yourTable
    WHERE colID = @idColumn;

    WITH substrTable AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select 0)) AS RowNum, value 
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@strToSubstr, ' ')
    )
    select value from substrTable
    where RowNum = 3;

    SELECT @idColumn = MIN(colID) 
    FROM @yourTable
    WHERE colID > @idColumn;
END
```

Comment: There are 2 problems here, in truth. 1. `STRING_SPLIT` is documented to *not* guarantee the order the values are returned; you could easily end up with the data in the wrong order. 2. A `WHILE` loop will be very slow; SQL is a set based language and you should be using set based solutions.